# Prove change of variable that transforms Ricatti ODE into exact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following exercise: "Prove that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions of the Ricatti ODE $y'=f(t)+g(t)y+h(t)y^2$, then the change of variable $y=\frac{y_1-ty_2}{1-t}$ transforms it into an exact ODE." I have done several exercices similar to this one in which I showed that, given $P(t,y)+Q(t,y)y'=0$, $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$, proving in this way it was exact. But in this case I don't know which dependent variable is the one that introduces the change of variable instead of $y$, so I can't compute. Thanks.

Comment: Substitute $y(t) = (y_1-ty_2)/(1-t)$ into the ODE and see what you get.

Comment: Ok @Doug, after substituting and using several times that $y_1'=f(t)+g(t)y_1+h(t)y_1^2$ and $y_2'=f(t)+g(t)y_2+h(t)y_2^2$, I have arrived to the expression $th(t)(y_1-y_2)^2=2ty_2-(y_1+y_2)$ but I don't know really how to continue.

Comment: It's ***Riccati***. The Italian word “ricatti” is the plural of “ricatto”, that is, *blackmail*.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ y=\frac{y_1-ty_2}{1-t} $$
and then one has
$$ y'=\frac{y_1'(t)-t y_2'(t)-y_2(t)}{1-t}+\frac{y_1(t)-t y_2(t)}{(1-t)^2}. \tag1$$
Using
$$ y_i'=f(t)+g(t)y_i+h(t)y_i^2, i=1,2$$
and $y_1=(1-t)y+ty_2$
in (1), one has
$$ y'=\frac{(t-1) f(t)+ [(t-1) g(t)+(t-1) h(t)-1]y+y_2(t)}{t-1}. \tag2$$
Now write (2) as
$$ y'=p(t)y+q(t) \tag3 $$
where
$$ p(t)=g(t)+h(t)-\frac{1}{t-1}, q(t)=f(t)+\frac{y_2}{t-1}. $$
Now (3) is a first order linear DE and it is easy to solve or transform it into an exact DE. In fact, multiplying both sides by $\mu(t)$ gives
$$ \mu(t)[p(t)y+q(t)]dt-\mu(t)dy=0. \tag4 $$
Then
$$ M(t,y)=\mu(t)[p(t)y+q(t)], N=-\mu(t). $$
So
$$ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial t}$$
gives
$$ \mu(t)=e^{-\int p(t)dt} $$
so that (4) is exact.

Comment: Ok @xpaul, I have understood it. But you have applied this process because the expression (2) obtained after using the change of variable and the $y_1$ and $y_2$ solutions  is equivalent to the given DE, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.